# Can't remove body class previosly added with click event

Tags: javascript

I'm missing something, probably related with `bind`, but I can not see what and where. I can add a class to a body tag, but I can not remove it latter.

```
const add_body_class = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-add-class');

add_body_class.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
     document.body.classList.add('foobar');
  })
});

const remove_body_class = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-remove-class');

remove_body_class.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
     // this doesn't work
     document.body.classList.remove('foobar');
     // click event works
     console.log("clicked");
  })
});
```

BTW I need to use multiple selectors and `document.querySelectorAll` because of multiple instances, and I can not change any of HTML code.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [Seems to work fine?](https://jsfiddle.net/48m2h0ef/)

Comment: @Ivar Yes, I though the same, but the class still remains?

Comment: Did you check the Fiddle I linked in the previous comment? Clicking the "Add" button adds the class (and thus the yellow background) and clicking "Remove" removes the class (and the background becomes white again). The class doesn't remain.

Comment: @Ivar by class the maybe Darko means the attribute and not the value, even we remove the class from body tag still class attributes remains

Comment: yes, I even added multiple buttons, and it works on Fiddle, but it doesn't work for on my project

Comment: Then you'll need to provide a [mcve]. We can't tell you the problem without being able to reproduce it.

Comment: @shubhampatil sorry if I wasn't clear, I meant on body class value

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me, I just wrapped it inside a DOMContentLoaded listener.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<button class="btn-add-class">Add</button>
<button class="btn-add-class">Add</button>
<button class="btn-add-class">Add</button>
<hr>
<button class="btn-remove-class">Remove</button>
<button class="btn-remove-class">Remove</button>
<button class="btn-remove-class">Remove</button>
</body>
<style>
.foobar{
  background-color: yellow;
  }
</style>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
const add_body_class = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-add-class');

add_body_class.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
     document.body.classList.add('foobar');
     console.log("added");
  })
});

const remove_body_class = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-remove-class');

remove_body_class.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
     // this doesn't work
     document.body.classList.remove('foobar');
     // click event works
     console.log("removed");
  })
});
})
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, it was wrapped already I didn't added the wrapper in the code